# Centralizar div container materialize

Tags: html, css, framework, materialize

Tenho a seguinte estruta no meu `HTML`:

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="container center-align">
        <h1 class="grey-text text-lighten-5">Análise de Sistemas</h1>
        <span><b class="grey-text text-lighten-5">Tutoriais, Dicas, Tecnologia</b></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

O `CSS` da classe `image`:

```
.image {
    background-image: url("../images/vingadores.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Conforme imagem abaixo a `<div class="container center-align">` não fica centralizada, gostaria que ela ficasse no meio da imagem que é a div `<div class="image">`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

> Já olhei aqui no Stack e as Q&A sobre centralizar `div` não me ajudaram.

**OBS:** Estou usando o Framework [Materialize.](http://materializecss.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de centralizar ambos horizontalmente e verticalmente uma div. Neste caso como não temos nem sabemos os valores `height` nem o valor `width` de nenhuma das classes `container` ou `center-align` podemos usar um truque que vai alinhar perfeitamente esta div sem ser preciso saber os seus valores `width` ou `height`.

Eis como isto pode ser concretizado:

```
.center-align {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Fazendo isto, agora a `<div class="image">` não vai estar a obedecer a `parent div` e vai simplesmente sair fora da class `.image` e obedecer ao `body` em vez disso. Então nós precisamos fazer com que ela obedeça à class `.image` para fazer o texto obedecer a esta classe para que esta fique dentro dela e não estar ir para fora dela. Então iremos dar uma `position:relative;` para ela:

```
.image {
    background-image: url("../images/vingadores.jpg");
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center; /* Adicionalmente iremos mudar esta linha que antigamente era align-content: center; para podermos alinhar o texto ao centro */
    position: relative;
}
```

Aqui tens um exemplo abaixo:

```css
.center-align {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
    /* código abaixo não relevante, só para o estilo! */
    color: #fff;
    background:#000;
    padding: 0 20px 10px 20px;
}
.image {
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    
    /* código abaixo não relevante, só para o estilo! */
    background: url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/zeroxkAEKyM/maxresdefault.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <div class="container center-align">
        <h1 class="grey-text text-lighten-5">Análise de Sistemas</h1>
        <span><b class="grey-text text-lighten-5">Tutoriais, Dicas, Tecnologia</b></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito Bom!! Obrigado!!